# PHP include/require not working

Tags: php, html

I am currently working on a website where I am attempting to add the header and menu links recursively to every page using the PHP include command. Whenever I attempt to run the specific PHP file as include, it doesn't show up. When I run it as require, the page loads blank.

After doing a bit of research, I've found the most common resolution to the problem; making sure the index.php and the pages you're trying to include need to have the .php extension; which they do.

Here's basically what I'm working with:
The site master page is: 
www.humanistsofutah.org (or also known as index.php)
Host is Xmission webhosting. 
openbased_dir is set to /var/www/vhosts/humanistsofutah.org/

The file that I'm referencing for the PHP code is called Houbodyphp.php

**Here's the index.php code:**

```
     <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <?php 
    $INC_DIR = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/includes"; ?>
    <?php include($INC_DIR. "houbodyphp.php"); ?>

   <title>Humanists, Humanism, and Rational Thinking in Utah</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">                                                </meta>
    <link href="houart.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css/php">


    <meta name="keywords" content="humanism, humanist, science, naturalism,      skepticism, non-theism, atheism, atheist, agnosticism, rational, rationalist, freethought, freethinker, scientific method">
    </head>
    <body> 
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="97%" summary="Humanists of Utah (Border)"> 
    <tbody> 
     <tr> 
     <td width="20%"> 
    &nbsp;
        &nbsp;
```

**And here's what the HouBodyphp.php code looks like:**

```
         <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
         <html>
         <head>
         <style>
          tbody {position: relative}
         </style>
          <body>
```

```
             <table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="1" width="100%" summary="Humanists of Utah"> 
                 <tbody> 
                  <tr> 
                 <td align="center" colspan="6" width="50%"><a href="http://humanistsofutah.org/wordpress/"><img width="600" alt="" style="width: 600px;" src="picture_library/UtahbkgLogoCORRECT.png" /></a></td> 
                 </tr> 
                 <tr> 
                <td align="center" width="50%" colspan="6" rowspan="4" valign="middle" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="white-space: nowrap;"> 
            <div style="text-align: center;"><b><span style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 9pt; background-image: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-size: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; background-position: initial; background-repeat: initial;"><a href="http://humanistsofutah.org/wordpress/what-is-humanism/">What is Humanism?  </a>               <br /><br /></span></b> 
            </div> 
            <div style="text-align: center;"><span "="" background-size:="" background-origin:="" background-clip:="" background-position:="" background-repeat:="" initial;"="" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 9pt; background-image: initial;"><a href="http://humanistsofutah.org/wordpress/get-involved/upcoming-events/">Meeting Information and Contacts</a>&nbsp;-&nbsp;</span>          <span font-family:="verdana" ;="" font-size:="9pt" background-image:="" initial;="" background-attachment:="" background-size:="" background-origin:="" background-clip:="" background-position:="" background-repeat:="" initial;"=""><a style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 9pt;" href="search.html">Search HoU Website</a>&nbsp;-&nbsp;</span> <span style="font-size: 9pt; font-family: Verdana;"><a href="http://humanistsofutah.org/wordpress/archivalsample/">Archive</a></span> <span style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 9pt;">&nbsp;</span> 
            </div> 
            <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 9pt; background-image: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-size: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; background-position: initial; background-repeat: initial;"><a style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 9pt;" href="http://humanistsofutah.org/wordpress/membership/our-members/">Our Members</a></span> <span style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 9pt; background-image: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-size: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; background-position: initial; background-repeat: initial;">&nbsp;-&nbsp;<a href="http://humanistsofutah.org/wordpress/about-2/historical-humanists/">Historical Humanists</a></span> <span style="font-size: 9pt;">&nbsp;-&nbsp;</span><span style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 9pt; background-image: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-size: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; background-position: initial; background-repeat: initial;"><a style="font-size: 9pt;" href="http://humanistsofutah.org/wordpress/media/recommended-reading/">Recommended Reading</a></span></p> 
            <div style="text-align: center;"><a href="http://humanistsofutah.org/wordpress/related-websites/"><span style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 9pt; background-image: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-size: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; background-position: initial; background-repeat: initial;">Our Favorite Websites</span></a>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<a href="http://humanistsofutah.org/wordpress/related-websites/"> <span style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 9pt; background-image: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-size: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; background-position: initial; background-repeat: initial;">Links</span></a>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<span style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 9pt; background-image: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-size: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; background-position: initial; background-repeat: initial;"><a href="www.humanistsofutah.org/wordpress">Great Quotes</a></span> 
            </div> </td> 
        </tr> 
      </tbody> 
    </table></td>
```

``

I know some of this is probably completely wrong and off base, and I apologize in advance for that, but I have been struggling with this for weeks and desperately need help.

Thank you for your time,

Eric Whittaker

Comment: You have no slash between your include path and file name. Also, turn on error reporting. You'd have solved this by now if you did.

Comment: `includeshoubodyphp.php` isn't your folder right? *et voilà* ;-)

Comment: It should work with just include("houbodyphp.php"); What's the $inc_dir for?

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP will try to include file `includeshoubodyphp.php` because of the following code:

```
<?php include($INC_DIR. "houbodyphp.php"); ?>
```

Add a `/` here:

```
<?php include($INC_DIR. "/houbodyphp.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response Praveen! Unfortunately, that didn't do the trick : (

Comment: To give some further detail; since I need to add this header to every page on the website, I am using the following URL as a test (to make sure the header is appearing on every page): http://humanistsofutah.org/2013/CCC-Jan-13.html